# Create top by rating when wins and looses are comma-separated strings of user ids

Tags: mysql

I have a table of all games: game id, winners and loosers.
Winners and loosers are varchars which are comma-separated lists of ids, for example:

```
| id | winners | loosers |
|  1 | 10,24,3 |34,158,71|
```

I'd like to create a query to select a top of users (top-30 for ex.) ordered by rating which is amount of wins divided by amount of looses. But the table with all users has 6k rows and iterating over it to make a top takes 1 minute which is too long for me. Any way to make it simpler?

I got an idea to iterate over the games table, put user_id, wins and looses to a temporary table, and then select the result, but I'm not sure how to make this right.

Desired output format:

```
| user_id | rating |
```

and only using mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any way to make it simpler?

Glad you asked. Yes, there is a great way to make this simpler:

*Stop storing sets of discrete values as comma-separated strings.*

SQL works best if you store one discrete value per column on a given row, if you later need to do calculations on the individual values.

Store two tables: The first table has one row for each game. The second table has one row per user per game, and an attribute that says whether they won or lost.

| game_id | user_id | won |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 1 | 34 | 0 |
| 1 | 71 | 0 |
| 1 | 158 | 0 |

Now you can query it more simply to get the percentage of wins to losses per user:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(NULLIF(won, 0)) / COUNT(*) AS percent_wins
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Yeah this is absolutely right, just wanted to know if there's a solution with no restructuring large amount of data.

Comment: You should bite the bullet and fix your data.